# Kinetic energy of system is homogeneous quadratic function of generalised velocities $\dot q_i$

Tags: classical-mechanics

According to Hamilton's equation....the relation
$$
2T = \sum_ip_i\dot q_i
$$
is obvious.  But How would I show that kinetic energy is homogeneous  quadratic function of generalised velocities $\dot q_i$?

Comment: Please use LaTeX to format mathematical symbols and formulas. Here is a link to a quick tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Please edit and expand your question. To properly compose formulas that are then displayed with correct formatting, see [mathjax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1), a discussion of additional resources can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto/4658#4658). Please add more context to your question, it is no clear what you are asking specifically. For the general topic, consult a textbook on Hamilton mechanics, Arnol'd is nice if somewhat advanced,...

Comment: This is a very good question in physics stack exchange